# Proof of convergence in original Metropolis algorithm paper

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, monte-carlo, metropolis-hastings

I've been trying to understand the [original paper](https://bayes.wustl.edu/Manual/EquationOfState.pdf) in which the Metropolis algorithm was proposed, specifically the proof of convergence given in section II.

The final step in the proof gives the inequality $$(\nu_r/\nu_s) > [\exp(-E_r/kT)/\exp(-E_s/kT)],\tag{6}$$ The paper says that the above inequality plus ergodicity implies convergence, but I don't see how this follows. I can see that $\exp(-E_r/kT)/\exp(-E_s/kT) = \exp(-\Delta E/kt)$, which is the threshold used when deciding to accept the new state. But in the algorithm, we choose $\xi_3$ uniformly between 0 and 1, and accept iff $\xi_3 < \exp(-\Delta E/kt)$. I don't see how $\xi_3$ is related to $\nu_r/\nu_s$, or even why we care about the quantity $\nu_r/\nu_s$.

Another question I have is that in more modern presentations of the Metropolis algorithm, the proof of convergence basically goes like this: (1) show that the acceptance probabilities imply that the transition probabilities satisfy detailed balance, (2) show that detailed balance implies a stationary distribution. However, in the proof in this paper, there is no mention of detailed balance or anything resembling it. What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $\nu_r$ is the invariant measure. The claims made (preceding (5) and (6)) are that if $E_r > E_s$, then

- the flow from $r$ to $s$ is $\nu_r P_{rs}$
- the flow from $s$ to $r$ is $\nu_s P_{sr} \cdot \exp \left( - \left[ E_r - E_s \right] / kT \right)$

In (5) and (6), the reasoning is that if these two terms are **not** equal, then the system is **not** at equilibrium.

If one takes $\nu_r = \exp \left( - E_r / kT \right)$, then the system is at equilibrium, and thus is an invariant measure for the Markov chain constructed.

Note that `equilibrium' here is used synonymously with 'in detailed balance'.